# Is there a inbuilt tag in JSF 2.0 that can support Application/PDF content Type

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm performing a F:AJAX call where I receive a byte Stream output whose content type is application PDF. I want this bytestream to be loaded in a JSF equivalent tag which should make me specify the content type as "Application/PDF" during tag declaration. Also, f:View fails saying content type not supported. Any JSF specific tags to cater this. Thanks.

Comment: Try with OmniFaces: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Faces https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.6/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.java#L2286 https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.6/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/FacesLocal.java#L1585

Answer (score 0):

Use `iframe` tag. This line shows how to use it:

```
<iframe src="foo.pdf" width="600" height="400" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

If you also want to hide the (default) border, add `frameBorder="0"`.

There is also pdf.js library that allows to browse pdf in browser. https://blog.oio.de/2014/04/11/integrating-pdf-js-pdf-viewer-web-application/

Comment: Iframe and frameset can ease the work but is thr a way within jsf!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no there isn't such a tag**.

To be honest there's no need to change it, since using HTML for this is fine and really the simplest way. You can use `IFRAME` (like Jay Smith shows you) or `OBJECT`.

The same way is presented on [PrimeFaces's showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml):

```
<h3>PDF</h3>
<object type="application/pdf"    
        data="/showcase/resources/demo/media/guide.pdf?pfdrid_c=true" 
        height="300px" width="100%" internalinstanceid="3">

    Your browser can't display pdf,
    <a href="/resources/demo/media/guide.pdf">click</a>
    to download pdf instead.
</object>
```